# How to enable the Spring Boot Security Basic authentication to Hystrix.stream?

Tags: spring, spring-security, hystrix

I need to enable the basic authentication to http://localhost:8080/hystrix.stream.

I have added the Spring Security It secures all other endpoints except hystrix.stream.

Is this possible to protect the hystrix.stream with Spring Boot Security basic authentication.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to enable security for your management endpoint:

```
management.security.enabled = true
```

Next, you can configure access to the `hystrix.stream` like you do for any other endpoint:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/hystrix.stream")
                .authenticated(); // or whatever you like in here
            // rest of your security config
    }

}
```